# Proving or disproving two statements for metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

So let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.
I have to either prove or disprove the following statements. Each of them separately.
1)
For any bounded subset $A\subseteq X$ this is true: $\mathrm{diam}(A)=\mathrm{diam}(
\overline{\rm A})$

2)
For any bounded subset $A\subseteq X$ with non-empty interior it's true that $\mathrm{diam}(A)=\mathrm{diam}(\mathrm{int}(A))$

So I know what interior is:
$\mathrm{Int}(A)= \{x\in M\;\;|\;\; \exists r > 0 \mathrm{\;such\;that\;}  B_{r}(x) \subset A \}$

So I have to use this for the second one
.

So radically, I don't know how to start to solve this, any hints even would help, but I woupd really need help with it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try writting down the definition of the diameter of a set. That might give you some ideas. For instance, it is clear that $\operatorname{diam}(A)\leq \operatorname{diam}(\overline{A})$, do you see why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is TRUE.

Hint:
Let $a,b\in \bar{A}$ be two points. Then there exist sequences $\{a_n\}\subseteq A$ and $\{b_n\}\subseteq A$ such that $a_n\rightarrow a$ and $b_n\rightarrow b$. Then 
$$d(a,b)\leq d(a,a_n)+d(a_n,b_n)+d(b,b_n)$$
As $a_n\rightarrow a$ and $b_n\rightarrow b$, we have $d(a_n,b_n)\rightarrow d(a,b)$.

(2) is FALSE.

Consider $A=(\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1])\cup(0,1/2)$.

Answer (score 2):

1) If you have a point of $\bar{A}$, how did it get there? Recall the definition of a closure, and the definition of diameter. Try to prove that, indeed, the diameter of a closure is the same as the diameter of the set.

2) Think about a set made up of some open ball and another point, far away.